# How to parse encrypted data in function dataRecieved in twisted?

Tags: python, encryption, twisted, twisted.internet

In my project I inherited twisted protocol `from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol`, As we know, I should do something packet manipulation in the function `dataRecieved`, However, the [doc](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.2.0/api/twisted.internet.protocol.Protocol.html#dataReceived) said:

> data: a string of indeterminate length. Please keep in mind that you will probably need to buffer some data, as partial (or multiple) protocol messages may be received! I recommend that unit tests for protocols call through to this method with differing chunk sizes, down to one byte at a time.

So my data format is that:

`packet len | payload
2 bytes    | variable bytes`

But things become complected if I want to encrypt my data, How should I do then?

Should I encrypt both packet length and payload? then how to judge if the packet is end?

Or should I encrypt only the payload, then alter the packet length ? what if the encrypted payload length is larger than the max value of 2bytes?

Plus: If I use raw socket instead of twisted, can I omit the 2 bytes packet len prefix?

Thanks!

Comment: `Payload = encrypted_data` don't mix packet pattern with payload content. **You can't encrypted any `ETH` packet header or information contents !**.

Comment: Of course it's not ETH packet header. packet len is my self-defined pattern in IP layer payload.

Comment: `Payload= Sub_header + Encrypted_data + Encrypted_data_Len(free size)`. Payload is your message can define any parameter without quota. A `ETH` packet not have only single header, can use your data pattern or `RFC` design.